# Linear database design

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship

I have a question about database relationship

I am trying to build a monitoring system with the following rules :

- `Channels` belongs to one `Sensor`
- `Sensors` belongs to one `Device`
- `Devices` belongs to one `Probe`
- `Probes` belongs to one `Core`

Here is a preview of the tables

```
+-------------+    +-------------+
| Cores       |    | Probes      |
+-------------+    +-------------+
| id          |    | id          |
| fields ...  |    | fields ...  |
+-------------+    | core_id     |
                   +-------------+

+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+
| Devices     |    | Sensors     |    | Channels    |
+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+
| id          |    | id          |    | id          |
| fields ...  |    | fields ...  |    | fields ...  |
| probe_id    |    | device_id   |    | sensor_id   |
+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+
```

Now to get the `core_id` of a spécific `channel` or the full list of a `core`'s `channels`, I need to join all the five tables.

My question is, would it be better to have all tables linked together like the following example or it's a bad database design.

- Cores(id, fields...)
- Probes(id, fields..., core_id)
- Devices(id, fields..., core_id, probe_id)
- Sensors(id, fields..., core_id, probe_id, device_id)
- Channels(id, fields..., core_id, probe_id, device_id, sensor_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to consider is: "*can `X` exist out of the context of `Y`?*". Design changes depending on the answer. Based on your question, and design, these are the answers:

```
|            Question                 |Answer|
+-------------------------------------+------+
|Can a core exist independently?      | Yes  |
|Can a probe exist without a core?    | No   |
|Can a device exist without a probe?  | No   |
|Can a sensor exist without a device? | No   |
|Can a channel exist without a sensor?| No   |
```

As per these answers, a viable logical design may be:

```
-- Core COR exists.
--
core {COR}
  PK {COR}
```

```
-- Probe number PRO_NO of core COR exists.
--
probe {COR, PRO_NO}
   PK {COR, PRO_NO}

FK {COR} REFERENCES core {COR}
```

```
-- Device number DEV_NO of probe number PRO_NO
-- of core COR exists.
--
device {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO}
    PK {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO}

   FK {COR, PRO_NO} REFERENCES
probe {COR, PRO_NO}
```

```
-- Sensor number SNS_NO of device number DEV_NO,
-- of probe number PRO_NO, of core COR exists.
--
sensor {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO}
    PK {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO}

    FK {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO} REFERENCES
device {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO}
```

```
-- Channel CHN_NO of sensor number SNS_NO,
-- of device number DEV_NO, of probe number PRO_NO,
-- of core COR exists.
--
channel {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO, CHN_NO}
     PK {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO, CHN_NO}

    FK {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO} REFERENCES
sensor {COR, PRO_NO, DEV_NO, SNS_NO}
```

- Is this a bad design? *No*.
- Is it logically sound? *Yes*.
- What about normalization? *5NF (with ... attributes)*.
- Is it OK for a physical implementation? *Yes, maybe, no, depends*.

---

*Say* that you are considering physical design and are concerned about width of keys and index sizes. At this point you decide to follow the natural hierarchy and have a single column identifier for each entity, even if it can not exist out of the context of another one.

```
-- Core COR exists.
--
core {COR}
  PK {COR}
```

```
-- Probe PRO of core COR exists.
--
probe {PRO, COR}
   PK {PRO}

   FK {COR} REFERENCES core {COR}
```

```
-- Device DEV of probe PRO exists.
--
device {DEV, PRO}
    PK {DEV}

    FK {PRO} REFERENCES probe {PRO}
```

```
-- Sensor SNS of device DEV exists.
--
sensor {SNS, DEV}
    PK {SNS}

    FK {DEV} REFERENCES device {DEV}
```

```
-- Channel CHN of sensor SNS, exists.
--
channel {CHN, SNS}
     PK {CHN}

     FK {SNS} REFERENCES sensor {SNS}
```

This one matches your initial design.

- Is this a bad design? *No*.
- Is it logically sound? *Yes*.
- What about normalization? *5NF (with ... attributes)*.
- Is this better? *Yes, maybe, no, depends*.

Make sure you do not allow `NULLs`. Allowing `NULLs` for `FKs` would basically answer "yes" to all "*can `X` exist without`Y`?*" questions, and lead to completely different design (schema).

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Answer (score 1):

repeating the extra foreign keys is denormalized and will cause you trouble.

it should look like this:

```
Cores(id, fields...)
Probes(id, fields..., core_id)
Devices(id, fields..., probe_id)
Sensors(id, fields..., device_id)
Channels(id, fields..., sensor_id)
```

also - style points.  your table names should be singular - the define one row of the contents. so Core, Probe, Device etc.