# What are the drawbacks of inserting a "grandparent" foreign key in a table to avoid excessive joins?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Or, more precisely, something like a great-grandparent key.

I've got a multitenant website, each tenant can have many forums, each forum can have many threads, each thread can have many posts. There is an API where a tenant can request info about anything all the way down to a single post. But to verify they're allowed to do so, I might be looking at the `thread_id` in `posts`, then the `forum_id` in `threads`, then the `tenant_id` in `forums`, and all I was really after was `tenant_id` to verify it matches the tenant making the request.

Putting a `tenant_id` field all the way down the chain is probably a violation of some sort of normal form as it's redundant information, but the performance hit to all those joins is impossible to ignore, and there are times where I don't *need* any of that joined information except the single column. Adding `tenant_id` to all the columns will also make data exporting of a single tenant absurdly simple.

But I don't want the database police to come knocking on my door and take me away. I learned relational DBs in college with an emphasis on minimalism and normalization, so intentionally denormalizing the database feels like a sacrilege. But space is stupidly cheap and storing one more int is not going to break the bank. Am I missing anything obvious here? Just keep up with the referential integrity and I feel like I should be fine?

Comment: Depends, take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129649/linear-database-design/61144332#61144332

Comment: Interesting, thank you. And it's sort of the logical extension of the question. If I've got the parent and the great-grandparent, I may as well add the grandparent. You never know when it'll come up, and it can still maintain referential integrity.

Comment: RE: DB-police, join-speed etc; I have a rant about that (external site)
https://www.damirsystems.com/forgotten-simplicity/

Answer (score 2):

If denormalizing the database by storing redundant data gets you the performance you need and cannot get otherwise, then do what you have to do.

I'll only alert you to the problems:

1. Wasted space is probably the least of your problems.
2. You need to keep the various redundant foreign keys synchronized. That burden is either on your application or (better) on the database, where you use triggers to update all copies.
3. As a consequence of 2., the performance of data modifications will suffer.