# In grand parents-parents-children, is it okay for children to hold foreign key of a grand parent for easy navigation without multiple joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

Suppose we have `Users` that have `Blogs`, blogs have `Posts`, and posts have `Comments`, all of which are one-to-many relationships.

Normally each entity would only hold the foreign key of its immediate parent. To navigate from the top level to bottom level, multiple joins will be used.

The DB provider is PostgreSQL. I'm using Entity Framework Core so the queries will be translated either via multiple `Include` and `ThenInclude` from the top level or a `Where` clause with multiple levels of navigation from the bottom level.

But in this application, we **frequently** need to query a `User` and all of its associated `Comments`.

In this case, does it make sense to add an additional `User` foreign key in `Comment` and matching navigation properties so that the navigation can be made with just one join instead of multiple ones? I'd assume this is good for performance and convenience.

Note that the real application has more than 4 levels, and **frequently** is the important pattern here.

Comment: Premature optimisation.  Only de-normalise a structure for performance tuning ***when*** you can ***prove*** that the bottle neck you're addressing is actually present.

Comment: The only problem is that this creates "cycles or multiple cascade paths" issue for SqlServer, hence you won't be able to use the normal cascade delete. Otherwise I think it is quite common to have for instance `TenantId` column in each table for multi-tenant databases, event though it is really needed only in "top level" tables - very similar to your scenario.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for pointing that out. I haven't tested it myself yet but I'm using PostgreSQL, do you happen to know if it's a known problem for PostgreSQL too?

Comment: I know it is SqlServer issue - other databases like Oracle have no such limitation. I can\t say for PostgreSQL, you have to check/test. At least EF Core is not enforcing that limitation like EF6, the decision is left to the database provider.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129649/linear-database-design/61144332#61144332